# X Windows on Ubuntu 16.04 command-line resize infinite loops sometimes?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, xorg, window-management

### Background

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop edition and I'm having trouble resizing windows from command-line commands.  I recently switched to Fluxbox as my windowing manager and have had a strong interest in keybindings that run command-line commands to operate on window positions.  I hit some snags with resizing windows though and can't figure out what's going on.

In Fluxbox the keybinding actions to resize windows to percentages of the screen sometimes cause the window to resize, then slowly shrink, then resize again, then slowly shrink, repeating for a while until it either stops at some completely incorrect size, or never stops.  I assumed it was a Fluxbox issue and started trying to use xdotool and wmctrl instead, but the same problem's occuring.

### Problem

I've replicated this problem on a VMWare guest install of Ubuntu 16.04 and a native install of Ubuntu 16.04.  I've also repeated it under different window managers on each system: XFCE4, KDE, Fluxbox, Unity, Fluxbox built from source.

If I have a window with an arbitrary size, running either of these commands will intermittently:

1. work perfectly and resize to the requested size
2. resize to the wrong size
3. resize (not necessarily to the right size), slowly shrink the width and height of the window, resize again, and repeat these steps for a while until it finally stops (usually at some incorrect size)
4. The same as #3 above and it stops at height 1 with some width smaller than that requested.
5. The same as #3 above, but it never stop resizing and shrinking

Numbers #4 and #5 above are the most common and problematic since the only way to resolve it is to close the window and open it again.

I ran these commands on a large display area that's much larger than the sizes specified.  The commands I tried (for target size 900x900) are:

```
wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -o 0,-1,-1,900,900
wmctrl -i -r 0x01000004 -o 0,-1,-1,900,900
xdotool getactivewindow windowsize 900 900
xdotool getactivewindow windowsize --sync 900 900
xdotool windowsize 20971524 900 900
xdotool windowsize --sync 20971524 900 900
```

As you can see, I've tried both xdotool and wmctrl, using the automatic detection of the active window and the explicit specification of the active window (looked up using wmctrl and xdotool respectively).  I've also tried different sizes that are smaller or larger, windows for different programs than just a terminal, windows that aren't the current one, and moving the window at the same time.  None of them seem to make any difference in the outcome.
To try to debug the problem, I tried running strace on the xdotool command to see if it was stuck looping somewhere:

```
strace xdotool windowsize --sync 20971524 900 900 2>~/trace.log
```

I repeated this command until I got one that worked perfectly on the first try then repeated it until I got one that got stuck in an infinite loop, saving the trace logs separately.  I compared them to see what was different and the only things different were the window IDs involved.  That suggests to me it's not a problem communicating with the tool itself (unlikely since both wmctrl and xdotool have the same problem) or a problem communicating with an underlying framework (also unlikely).

### Question(s)

Where do I go from here, and where should I look to solve this?  Is there possibly a problem with Wayland vs XWindows since Wayland was introduced for Ubuntu in 16.04?  Is there a legacy XWindows I can/should try to solve it?  Is this just a bug in XWindows that everyone sees?  Are there other tools that might do the resize differently?  Am I not accounting for something in the resize command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with some windows and the "Window Geometry Hints".  Particularly with terminator (gnome version), there's a known issue where the Window Geometry Hints can/might/do hint that the window should be slightly smaller or larger, changing it's mind every time X resizes the window to the hinted size.

The solution at least for terminator (gnome version), is to disable the Window Geometry Hints in the configuration.  Each program having a problem may or may not have a solution individually.